# In python, how can I convert a numpy.matrix [[ a b] [c d]] into a string of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

Tags: python, numpy

In python, how can I convert `numpy.matrix([[a, b], [c, d]])` into a string of `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: ```[[ a b] [c d]]```? It is already invalid

Comment: What are `a`,`b`,..,?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `numpy.matrix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
import numpy as np

matrix = np.matrix([['a','b'],['c','d']])

matrix = matrix.flatten().tolist()[0]
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
arr.flatten()
```

`arr` is the numpy ndarray, in which case is your matrix [['a', 'b'], ['c','d']]

Document: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Answer (score 0):

If the "numpy martrix" is just a set of characters I wouldn't recommend using a numpy array at all.

You could concatenate both lists of strings by accessing the first [0] and second [1] elements of the lists within the outer list and reassigning the variable as one list of the 4 characters.

```
to_str = [['a','b'],['c','d']]
to_single_list = to_str[0]+to_str[1]
print(to_str)

returns: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

#to change variable values to one list

import numpy as np
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
to_str = [[a,b],[c,d]]
to_str = to_str[0]+to_str[1]
to_str
```

Comment: What if the four characters(a,b,c,d) are all float numbers? How can I convert it into a string ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']?

Comment: For example: how can I convert [[ 7. 10.] [15. 22.]] to ['7.', '10.', '15.', 22.']

Comment: Edited the solution hope that helps, should be the same for integers or floats... or any characters for that matter :)

Comment: Viable solution but Daniel's more efficient.